# Incremental backups and deleting files

Tags: windows, incremental-backup

I've been researching various backup software (free and paid) for a while now trying to find one that suits our needs.

Basically I want to backup a directory on our web server to a remote ftp server using incremental backups.

I've found a few bits of software that seem to support this but one thing that doesnt really seem to be supportted in the apps I've tried is files being deleted in the source directory dont get reflected in the incremental backups.

Is this a general principal of incremental backups that deleted files aren't tracked? Or have I just not found good backup software so far? Any suggestions of software that supports this

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'reflected in the incremental backups'? TSM's dsmc for example marks files as expired if they don't exist anymore on its next run.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for the ability to restore to a point in time of a particular backup, as well as only backing up the changed files since the last backup

Comment: Well, what timespan you have available depends on your retention policy on the backup server. Incremental backup should be supported by the major players in the backup solution market.

Comment: I've looked at quite a few small/medium sized apps and none really seem to support this, its only for 2 servers at the moment, can you suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

Rsync supports incremental backups and should suffice for your setup.

Have a look at this detailed introduction to [rsync and backup](http://webgnuru.com/linux/rsync_incremental.php)

Comment: I don't belive rsync in widnwos supports restoring to a particular backup of a certain time